# The shadow price is different under different simple algorithm

Tags: .net, algorithm, gurobi

i am using column generation algorithm to solve some problem,for example multi-commodity flow.I use **gurobi .net api**. When i try to get the **shadow price** of constraints, i found they are different with different **simplex algorithms**,such as primal simplex algorithm and dual simplex algorithm.In gurobi .net api, i set as follow:

```
GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv();
    env.Set(GRB.IntParam.Method, GRB.METHOD_PRIMAL);//primal   
    or env.Set(GRB.IntParam.Method, GRB.METHOD_DUAL);//DUAL
```

And also, with presolve and not presolve the result of shadow price will also be different，my setting are as follow:

```
 env.Set(GRB.IntParam.Presolve, 0);//turn off presolve
    env.set(GRB.IntParam.presolve,1);//with presolve
```

The problem i am confusing are:

1. in column generation algorithm,i should use which simplex algorithm,primal one or dual one?Should i turn off presolve or not?
2. i test the two kind of algorithm respectively, i found the shadow prices in dual simplex algorithm without presolve are more reasonable. So ,i set the GRBEnv as dual simplex algorithm and turn off presolve,but during column generation iteration, usually in 3th iteration, the shadow prices will be the result of primal simplex algorithm.Because i write the continue lp model into *.lp file, reread the model and solve with two kind of algorithm,the result of primal one is  the same as the result of column generation iteration, so why during iteration,the dual simplex algorithm will turn to primal algorithm.

Are there anybody can help me,thank you in advance.